# java using shell commands

Tags: java, shell, cp

So trying to use "cp" to copy a file from one location to another - the file is denominated with a file name containing white space ("test test"). When invoking command in the shell (bash) it works fine, but called from java it fails. I use escape characters. Code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

  private static String shellify(String path) {
    String ret = path;
    System.out.println("shellify got: " + ret);
    ret = ret.replace​(" ", "\\ ");
    System.out.println("shellify returns: " + ret);
    return ret;
  }    

  private static boolean copy(String source, String target) {
    String the_command = ""; // will be global later
    boolean ret = false;
    try {
      Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
      String source_sh = shellify(source);
      String target_sh = shellify(target);
      the_command = new String
    ("cp -vf " + source_sh + " " + target_sh);
      System.out.println("copy execing: " + the_command);
      Process p = rt.exec(the_command);
      InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader
    (new InputStreamReader(is));
      String reply = br.readLine();
      System.out.println("Outcome; " + reply);
      ret = (reply != null) && reply.contains("->");
    } catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    the_command = "";
    return ret;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String source = "test1/test test";
    String target = "test2/test test";
    if(copy(source, target))
      System.out.println("Copy was successful");
    else
      System.out.println("Copy failed");
  }

}
```

...and the outcome is this

```
shellify got: test1/test test
shellify returns: test1/test\ test
shellify got: test2/test test
shellify returns: test2/test\ test
copy execing: cp -vf test1/test\ test test2/test\ test
Outcome; null
Copy failed
```

whereas if I use bash the copy succeeded (big surprise).

```
Sino-Logic-IV:bildbackup dr_xemacs$ cp -vf test1/test\ test test2/test\ test
test1/test test -> test2/test test
```

Can anyone please tell me why this is? Copying files without white spaces works just fine.

/dr_xemacs

Comment: pretty sure that `Runtime` does not know about `\` - have you tried using the `exec` method that takes a string array for command (documentation for `exec` (one string): *"...the command string is broken into tokens using a StringTokenizer..."* - the tokenizer just uses `" \t\n\r\f"` to separate in tokens, `\` is just a *normal* character for it)

Comment: try something like `String[] command = { "cp",  "-vf ", source_sh, target_sh };`    (Note: `new String(text)` is mostly not really needed) (Note2: I think that backslash, quote and similar  interpretation is done by shells line reader, which is not used by `Runtime`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the arguments individually and they do not need escaping in shellify because the String[] version of exec provides each argument to the script separately as one argument even if they contain spaces:

```
String[]the_command = new String[] {"cp","-vf", source, target);
```

You may need to fix PATH available to Java VM if `cp` is not present in one of the PATH directories, or you could fully qualify the path to the executable cp in `the_command [0]`.

Your code is missing a line to check the `cp` / process exit code, add `waitFor` after consuming the STDOUT / `getInputStream()`:

```
int rc = p.waitFor();
```

Comment: Yup.  `exec` does not understand shell escapes and shell quoting, and will mess up if you try to execute a command string that uses them.